# JavaScript objects defined in different ways

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I'm fairly new to JavaScript and have a question regarding how objects are defined in below code snippet.

In the first instance `domStrings` object is defined as `domStrings=` and in the second instance the returning object is defined as `getinput:function()` what is the difference? And why if I change the returning object as `getinput=function`, it doesn't work? Please help me understand.

```js
var UIcontroller = (function() {
  var domStrings = {
    inputType: '.add__type',
    inputDescription: '.add__description',
    inputValue: '.add__value',
    addButton: '.add__btn'
  }
  return {
    getinput: function() {
      return {
        type: document.querySelector(domStrings.inputType).value,
        description: document.querySelector(domStrings.inputDescription).value,
        value: document.querySelector(domStrings.inputValue).value
      };
    },

    getDomStrings: function() {
      return domStrings;
    }
  }
})();
```

Comment: `domStrings` is a local variable in the function. `getInput` is an object property. They use different syntax.

Answer (score 0):

var domStrings is an `object`, objects have keys and values. `inputType, inputDescription, inputValue, addButton` are the keys and to the right of them are their values. You can access these by doing domStrings.inputType etc..

your function here is returning another object `return {}`
so getinput is actually a key for that object that's why it's defined like that

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, I still don't understand why in the first instance we're using "="sign and in the second instance we're using ":" when declaring the objects?

Answer (score 0):

This is an assignment and a declaration of two things:

```
var domStrings = {
    inputType: '.add__type',
    inputDescription: '.add__description',
    inputValue: '.add__value',
    addButton: '.add__btn'
  }
```

The variable `domstrings` is declared `var domStrings` and assigned `=`.

The variable now points to a location in memory. In that location in memory is an object that just got created.

An object in JavaScript is a dictionary: it is a set of key: value pairs, where the key can be a string or a number (or a Symbol, but don't worry about that for now).

The syntax for an object declaration is: { 'key': 'value' .... }.

The value can be any of the JS types - so, basically, a string, a number, void, a function, or another object.

You can point another variable at the same object in memory:

```
var a = domStrings;
a.inputType /// '.add__type'
```

If I now assign something else to `domStrings`:

```
domStrings = "nope"
```

`domStrings` is now pointing to a different location in memory:

```
domStrings.inputType // undefined - "nope" doesn't have a property inputType
```

`a` is still pointing to the object:

```
a.inputType // '.add__type'
```

So that statement does more than one thing. It declares a variable `domStrings`, it creates an object in memory, and it assigns the object to `domStrings` so that `domStrings` is a reference to the object.

Does that make that part clearer?

The second part:

What you are looking at there is called a closure. It is an IIFE - "Immediately Invoked Function Execution" - an immediately executing function that creates something like the singularity around a black hole. All of the internal machinery inside that function closure can see what's in there, but the value of `UIController` from outside is:

```
{
  getinput:() => {...},
  getDomStrings: () => domstrings
}
```

The `getDomStrings` function inside the UIController can see the `domstrings` variable, and pass a pointer to it back to code outside, but it is the only way anything outside the closure can access it.

The `getInput` function can also see it, and uses it to calculate the object that it returns when it is called.

So you can share code/data between functions inside a closure, but the only way anything outside the closure can see it is if you pass a reference out like `getDomStrings` does.

This is not very safe, because something outside this closure can call `getDomStrings` and get a reference to the object. It could then change the values in the object, which will change the behaviour of the `getInput` function in unpredictable ways.

It looks like the author wanted people to be able to read it that object, but not access it to modify it - in which case the way to do that is to return a copy of the object. That gives the caller an object with the same values, but not in the same memory location. Changing the copy will not change the object inside the closure.

If that wasn't their intention (making it read-only), they may have wanted the interface to that closure to have two functions instead of a function and an object.

I think it is the first, because it has a `get` but not a corresponding `set` method.

Because an object is a location in memory, and objects can be nested, copying an object is not trivial. You have to make a copy of all the objects inside it.

Check this out:

```
const a = {z: 3, k: {a: 3}}
const b = {...a} // "Spread" the keys of a onto b, a "shallow copy"

> b
{ z: 3, k: { a: 3 } } // looks b is a copy of a

> b.k.a = 4  // change a "deep value" of b
> b
{ z: 3, k: { a: 4 } }
> a
{ z: 3, k: { a: 4 } } // the object in a has changed!

> b.z = 2 // change a shallow property of b
> b
{ z: 2, k: { a: 4 } } // b has changed
> a
{ z: 3, k: { a: 4 } } // a has not
```

What happened here is that the objects `a` and `b` are in different memory locations. However, each of these objects has a property `k` that points to another location, and they point to the same location!

We can check this:

```
> a == b
false
> a.k === b.k
true // !
```

So returning `domStrings` from `getDomStrings` actually allows code outside this controller to change its behaviour.

Returning a spread would work in this case, because `domStrings` has no keys that have object references assigned to them.

I would write that as:

```
getDomStrings: function() {
   return {...domStrings};
}
```

That returns a copy that has the same values in it, so other parts of the program can use them to look things up, make decisions, or select things; but that copy cannot be used to mess with what's inside the closure.

There you go, the lesson on object references in JS that you didn't ask for. You're Welcome!

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, I still don't understand why in the first instance we're using "="sign and in the second instance we're using ":" when declaring the objects?

Comment: That is the syntax for object property declaration: { `key`: `value` }

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking at is called an [immediately invoked function expression (or IIFE, pronounced "iffy")](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately_invoked_function_expression). It is a work around for (ECMAScript 5) JavaScript to avoid hoisting and create closures.

In your example the variable domString is being assigned using the equals sign and the part on the right is something called an object literal and uses [object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript_syntax#Objects) literal syntax. The two functions being returned in the return statement are being declared as properties no different than they are in the object literal domStrings `inputType:` for example. The difference is that the value of properties in the return statement object literal are functions rather than strings. Variables and object properties in JavaScript can contain functions as their values.

In your example: domStrings is a private property of the UIcontroller function and is not accessible from anywhere else but inside the UIcontroller function. It exposes two public functions: getDomStrings and getinput and returns them to be used by callers upon instantiation.

Those two methods have access to domStrings but outside of the UIcontroller function nothing else does unless you also return a reference to domString in the return statement.

You could call UIcontroller.getDomStrings() and UIcontroller.getinput() but you can not call UIcontroller.domStrings. Returning domStrings in the return statement would make it a public property of UIcontroller which anyone could change anywhere.

Hope that helps. Does that answer it for you?

Happy coding!!!

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, I still don't understand why in the first instance we're using "="sign and in the second instance we're using ":" when declaring the objects?